# components in QQuickWidget behave differently than in QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The ToolTip and ComboBox components do not close when the user clicks somewhere else on the window when using QQuickWidget, but they do close when using a QQuickView(ToolTip dissapears and the popup of the combobox closes).

Any ideas if some attributes need to be set to the QQuickWidget to have the same behaviour as the QQuickView.

UPDATE:
Clicking on the button will hide the combobox , but clicking anywhere else on the window will not make the combobox collapse.
main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/resources/qml/test.qml"));
    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
id: test_combo
width: 400
height: 500
RowLayout{
   ComboBox {
        width: 200
        model: [ "Banana", "Apple", "Coconut" ]
    }

    Button{
        text: "test"
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does for me while using QQuickWidget. Can you share code ?

Comment: `QQuickWidget` is an offscreen-window. The inner scene has no idea that you're clicking around elsewhere in the app, outside of `QQuickWidget`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue where my `ComboBox`'s `Popup` would not close when I clicked elsewhere in the window if it was in a `QQuickWidget`.

The `ComboBox` behaved as I expected in a qml `Window` or in a `QQuickView`.

The solution I found was to customize the `ComboBox`'s `Popup` and set the `modal` and `closePolicy` properties as follows:

```
ComboBox {
    popup.modal: true
    popup.closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
    model: [ "apples", "oranges", "pears" ]
}
```

The model there because you need a model to see the `Popup` in action.

Comment: You can set properties on the popup (e.g. `ComboBox { popup.modal: true }`) without overriding the whole popup with a custom one.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point—I've updated my answer to simplify the example.